# Firebase database better way to save FCM tokens to avoid duplicates

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to save FCM tokens to Firebase Database to send notifications. Is there a better way to do it?
Now I do it like this:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("users/${user.uid}/tokens").push().setValue(token)
```

This way, each time when the token is pushed, it has new unique id and can have same token.

**Could you please give me an advice? Or maybe I can do it with firebase functions which will remove duplicates.**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved this problem by using another way for saving tokens, now token saves like a key of the record.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("users/${user.uid}/tokens").child(token).setValue(true)
```

Comment: Could you expand upon your solution a bit more? Why did this approach helped solve your initial problem?

Comment: @anthonymonori In case of using this approach Firebase Database doesn't create a new record in the database if token the same. And I shouldn't do anything to remove duplicates.

Comment: This is indeed the right solution. Nodes with children of the form `"valueoftoken": true` are Firebase Database's equivalent of **set** collections. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value

Comment: can i use mongo db instead of firebase database to store token and user info?

Comment: @SumanthVarada Yes, you can create a rest api and simply save and fetch your tokens from mongo db.

Comment: You must do this to have onlyu one token                 firebaseDatabase.reference.child("users/${user!!.uid}/tokens").child("token").setValue(it)

Answer (score 4):

I would **advise against saving that information** in a database.

Take in consideration that:

> The registration token may change when:
>
> - The app deletes Instance ID
> - The app is restored on a new device
> - The user uninstalls/reinstall the app
> - The user clears app data.

[Source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register)

FirebaseInstanceId may be considered *PID* (personal identification data), so treat it accordingly - remember the new GDPR regulations kicking in March 2018 if you do business in the EU

**Instead, I would just use the token to register the user for push notifications where needed and send it to your FCM/GCM server.**

Comment: Thanks for the advice. My app sends tokens during the opening of the main screen and in onTokenRefresh() method of FirebaseInstanceIdService, also after sending a notification, all invalid tokens will be deleted. How do you think is it fine?

Comment: Depends on your FCM/GCM server setup (or you maybe using Amazon SNS, but none the less, you should not care about invalid tokens - Firebase will not be able to send any notifications to those. Your only concern should be to always re-register the user if: they have been previously agreed to get push notifications and when the token is refreshed. Always make sure you get the users consent/permission before sending them anything!

Comment: I understood, before sending a notification I should get user's consent. Thanks.